# Как образуется слово "годовалый"?

Tags: словообразование

Год - годовой - годовалый?

Но суффикс АЛ обычно используется для образования существительных: театр -  театрал, опахивать - опахало.

Какое значение в слове "годовалый" имеет формант АЛ, есть ли еще подобные схемы образования слов?

Спасибо за ваше внимание и ваши ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Год - годовой - годовалый?

У Тихонова так:

***год*** -> год-**ова**-ть -> годова-**л**-ый

===============================================

[Л (по Ефремовой) =](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136286)

> суффикс 1. Словообразовательная единица, выделяющаяся в именах
>   прилагательных со значением нахождения в состоянии, которое возникло в
>   результате действия, названного мотивирующим словом *(впалый, гнилой,
>   заплесневелый, запотелый, окаменелый, ошалелый, позеленелый, прелый,
>   служилый, умелый, усталый и т.п.)*

Comment: Да, глагол "годовать" не часто встречается в обычной речи, но в фольклоре  существует, например: "Поклонись трижды до земли; тебе здесь не час часовать, не год годовать, не век вековать (А. Ф. Вельтман. Кощей бессмертный).